# Assign css class using ng-class in angular js

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, angularjs, json

I'm using angularjs and I have data like this :

```
$scope.users = [{
name: "Pratik"
queue: [{number: "199"},{number: "111"}],
status: "OK"
}]
```

My view :

```
   .available{
    background-color: #00226f;
    color: #f8f8f8;
    }

 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3" ng-repeat="user in users">
    <span ng-class="{'available': user.queue[0].number == 111}" class="badges ">111</span>
</div>
```

My problem is that I want to assign the class "available" if the queue array in users contains the number "111" at any index. In the users array the `number:"111"` may appear at any index so in the view I can't always use `user.queue[1].number == 111` or `user.queue[1].number == 111` to assign the class. I want a solution which will check if the queue array contains `number:"111"` and assign the class of available accordingly.
I tried to do it like this : `ng-class="{'available': user.queue[i].number == 111}"` but it's not working.  How do I do it?

**This my current workaround to apply the class:**

```
ng-class="{'available': user.queue[0].number == 111 ||  user.queue[1].number == 111}"
```

Comment: Don't you have to use `ng-repeat` als to `queue`???

Comment: but I think that will also repeat the <span>

Comment: @pravinnavle check the updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code snippet

can achieve by using `lodash` js also using `_.filter`

`_.filter(array, { 'number': '111' }  )`

Ref: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#find

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

$scope.findObjectByKey = function(array, key, value) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i][key] === value) {
            return array[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
};

$scope.users = [{
    name: "Pratik",
    queue: [{number: "199"},{number: "666"}],
    status: "OK"
  },
  {
    name: "Pratik 2",
    queue: [{number: "111"},{number: "555"}],
    status: "OK 2"
  },
  {
    name: "Pratik 3",
    queue: [{number: "999"},{number: "888"}],
    status: "OK 3"
  }
  ];
  
  $scope.searcInArray =  function(array){
   // var obj = $scope.findObjectByKey(array, 'number', '111');
   
   // using loadsh
   var obj = _.filter(array, { 'number': '111' }  );
   return obj.length > 0;
  };



}
```

```css
.available{
   background-color: #00226f;
   color: #f8f8f8;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3" ng-repeat="user in users">
    <span ng-class="{'available' : searcInArray(user.queue)}" class="badges ">111</span>
 </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you tell me a similar function to sort data if there's no array. I mean I want a functionality will let me sort values which are not array like this ('name' , 'Pratik') instead of (array, 'number', '111'). So that if the name is Pratik then I'll set some other class to that element

Comment: i would suggest to include & use lodash https://lodash.com/ for sorting searching etc.

Comment: can you help me with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53700568/angularjs-custom-filter-to-check-for-values-inside-a-data-array)

Comment: @pravinnavle updated my answer with `lodash` using `_.filter` method. so use `_.filter(array, { 'number': '111' }  )` instead `findObjectByKey` method.

Comment: thanks you so much. this is really helpful to optimise the code

Comment: enjoy coding :) :)

Comment: please take a look at my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55591159/optimise-ng-bind-directive-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 1):

To check that condition where `111` appears at any index the easy fix could be to call a function that will check that property in the array and return `true` or `false` based on the condition. Something like below:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
$scope.users = [{
    name: "Pratik",
    queue: [{
      number: "111"
    }, {
      number: "119"
    }],
    status: "OK"
  },
  {
    name: "Pratik123",
    queue: [{
      number: "199"
    }, {
      number: "185"
    }],
    status: "OK"
  }];
  $scope.checkQueue = function(queue){
    return queue.find(({number})=>number === '111');
  }
}]);
```

```css
.available {
  background-color: #00226f;
  color: #f8f8f8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3" ng-repeat="user in users">
    <span ng-class="{'available': checkQueue(user.queue)}" class="badges ">{{user.name}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's working fine the way I have implemented it.  This is my current workaround ng-class="{'available111': user.queue[0].number == 111 ||  user.queue[1].number == 111}"

Comment: @pravinnavle glad to help. You can tick mark the answer if it was helpful to you :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add use `ng-repeat` to loop all queue and find how has `item.number == '111'`

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3" ng-repeat="user in users">
  <div ng-repeat="item in user.queue">
     <span ng-class="{'available': item.number == '111'}" class="badges ">111</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**NOTE!**

if you want show only the `item.number == '111'` you can use [`ng-hide/show`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide)